# Regex: match if any n-character combination is present

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use regex to match all strings which contain any n-character combination, please?

For example, I have a string such as 1212789 and want to match any 4-character combination of these numeral, therefore:

- **1212**656 – true
- **12**656**12** – true
- **12**7**9**3**2**6 - true
- 123455 - false
- 121654 - false

If this is possible using regex, how?

Thank you!

Comment: The easiest is to just use: `[1212789]` with the `global` flag - then you will get **4 matches (with one character in each)**. Normally you don't want duplicates in a character class, but it  doesn't matter and here it would be the easiest.

Comment: Maybe [`([1212789].*){4}`](https://regex101.com/r/q72dff/1) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

##### Check if pattern exits

The following regex can help you get true/false results (identify if a given pattern exists in a string). For the pattern '1234':

```
1.*2.*3.*4
```

For a given string, it will match everything that comes between the 4 digit pattern, essentially verifying the pattern exits in this string:

- **192934**076
- **12034001234**098723

---

##### Check number of occurrences of the pattern

Simply add `?` to make the regexp only match one occurrence

```
1.*?2.*?3.*?4
```